# How to fix "unchecked call to 'attachView(V)' as a member of raw type 'BasePresenter'"?

Tags: java, android, generics, mvp, dagger-2

I have already looked up many answers here about this issue but for the life of me I can't seem to fix this problem on my end and I need some help.

**BasePresenter:**

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<V> {

    private V mView;

    public void attachView(V view) { mView = view; }
    public void detachView() { mView = null; }

}
```

**BaseFragment:**

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<P extends BasePresenter> extends Fragment {

    @Inject protected P mPresenter;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mPresenter.attachView(this); // unchecked call to 'attachView(V)' as a member of raw type 'BasePresenter'
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mPresenter.detachView();
    }

}
```

**MyPresenter:**

```
public class MyPresenter extends BasePresenter<MyPresenter.MyView> {

    @Inject
    public MyPresenter() {}

    public interface MyView {}

}
```

**MyFragment:**

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment implements MyPresenter.MyView {}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, instead of

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<P extends BasePresenter> extends Fragment {
```

---

It should be

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<V, P extends BasePresenter<V>> extends Fragment {
```

or

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<P extends BasePresenter<BaseFragment<P>>> extends Fragment {
```

or

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends BaseFragment<V, P>, P extends BasePresenter<V>> extends Fragment {
```

Basically, make sure the `BasePresenter` is parametrized with something.

---

---

---

EDIT:

Okay, based on what you're actually trying to do, you should do it like this:

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<V> {

    private V mView;

    public void attachView(V view) { mView = view; }
    public void detachView() { mView = null; }
}

public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends BaseFragment<V, P>, P extends BasePresenter<V>> extends Fragment {

    protected abstract P getPresenter();

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPresenter().attachView(this); // unchecked call to 'attachView(V)' as a member of raw type 'BasePresenter'
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPresenter().detachView();
    }
}

public class MyPresenter extends BasePresenter<MyPresenter.MyView> {
    @Inject
    public MyPresenter() {}

    public interface MyView {}
}

public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment<MyFragment, MyPresenter> implements MyPresenter.MyView {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyFragmentComponent component = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getComponent().myFragmentComponent();
        component.inject(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blah, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

---

---

EDIT2: Based on provided example:

```
public class RexTester {
    // MAIN CLASS

    static class Rextester {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new MyFragment();
        }
    }

// MVP CODE

    interface BaseView {}

    final static class MyPresenter extends BasePresenter<MyPresenter.MyView> {

        public MyPresenter() {}

        public void executeAction() {
            mView.onCallback();
        }

        interface MyView extends BaseView {
            void onCallback();
        }

    }

    abstract static class BasePresenter<V extends BaseView> {

        protected V mView;

        public void attachView(V view) { mView = view;}
        public void detachView() { mView = null; }

    }

    final static class MyFragment extends BaseFragment<MyPresenter.MyView, MyPresenter> implements MyPresenter.MyView {

        private MyPresenter mPresenter;

        public MyFragment() {
            mPresenter = new MyPresenter();

            onResume(); // Mock onResume() lifecycle event!

            mPresenter.executeAction();

            onPause(); // Mock onPause() lifecycle event!
        }

        protected MyPresenter getPresenter() {
            return mPresenter;
        }

        @Override
        protected MyPresenter.MyView getThis() {
            return this;
        }

        public void onCallback() {
            System.out.println("Hello AndroidMVP!");
        }
    }

    abstract static class BaseFragment<V extends BaseView, P extends BasePresenter<V>> extends Fragment implements BaseView {

        protected abstract P getPresenter();

        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getPresenter().attachView(getThis());
        }

        protected abstract V getThis();

        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            getPresenter().detachView();
        }
    }

// ANDROID FRAMEWORK MOCK

    abstract static class Fragment {

        protected void onResume() {}

        protected void onPause() {}

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify this "Although if you are attaching the fragment as the view, then it should implement an interface that makes it a view."?

Comment: actually, I removed all that and just added something that would work.

Comment: Will take a closer look at this tomorrow at work. Thanks.

Comment: i looked at it now and fixed some raw type issues

Comment: I'm trying to get your suggestion working but I still have one problem... Please check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3wsN.gif

Comment: I don't think `@Inject P presenter;` will work, you'll need to specify `protected abstract P getPresenter();` and inject it into the child

Comment: Assuming you're right, how would my class definitions be? If they're the same as I just posted, I still have that compile issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that still doesn't compile. Failing on `MyFragment` class definition.

Comment: I still can't make it work, not sure if I'm doing something wrong...Hopefully this will help find the issue: http://rextester.com/NMZLVR39160

Comment: `BaseView` is apparently completely new. I have figured out the original example, but apparently I need to add another edit to show the second half involving BaseView

Comment: I added `BaseView` because I was getting 2 compile errors and that fixed one of them. The other is the one that remains. If you can get the original example working without `BaseView`, that works for me too :)

Comment: well I made it work with `BaseView`, heh; apparently not being lazy from my part and actually opening up an IDE helps. >.>

Comment: Everything makes sense to me know, I just having a hard time getting my head around all this... Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the type-variable declaration:

```
class BaseFragment<P extends BasePresenter>
```

BasePresenter is a generic class, so you need to specify what its type parameter is. From this snippet:

```
mPresenter.attachView(this);
```

It would seem that you expect BaseFragment to be bound to the type-variable V in BasePresenter - so I would rewrite your BaseFragment declaration as follows:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<P extends BasePresenter<BaseFragment<P>>> { ... }
```

That should take care of the unchecked warning. That said, I strongly suspect that what you are really after is something like this:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<P extends BasePresenter<V>, V> { ... }
```

Where V is an independent type-variable modelling the 'view'.

Comment: I could make your first solution working and I understand it, but seems too complicated. About the second one, I couldn't make it work. Could you post a working example based on my initial question code?

Comment: I guess you really need to think about what relationship you want between BaseFragment, BasePresenter and View. Can a BaseFragment associated with any BasePresenter? Or does it have to be a BasePresenter with a specific View?

Comment: Good question. But I'm finding it hard to answer with a comment... For instance, take the following [example](http://pastebin.com/MLwEczgK). I basically want to move the `attachView(this)` and `detachView()` logic to the `BaseFragment` so that each fragment extending the base one doesn't have to worry about that. I'd also like for `BaseFragment` to expose a protected `presenter` field that represents each presenter according to the fragment extending the base one. What's the best way to achieve this without any errors/warnings?